# Spring boot datasource configuration dynamically

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am working on Spring boot application which takes datasource from different
ip-adresses. So i pass those Ip-addresses as arguments.

So how can i configure datasource with that ip-address ??

i tried this piece of code

```
@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder
        .create()
        .username("")
        .password("")
        .url("")
        .driverClassName("")
        .build();
}
```

Was not helpful ,gave me error.

Comment: What do you mean by `from different ip-adresses`?

Comment: i have diff prod database servers...each need to connect accordingly to task assigned..so i pass that ip address of db server as arguments..

Comment: What exactly have you tried with this code? The IP of the database will be part of the URL.

Comment: String url = "jdbc:mysql://" + ipaddress + ":3306/" + db;  ......so the ipaddress and db will be passed by arguments.